# SQL Server between statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I have two columns, year and pay period (1, 2, 3, 4...).  I am racking my brain to try to figure out how to do a between based on these.

For example say I have:

```
2017      1
2017      2
2017      3
2017      4
-------------v   
2017      5
2017      6
...
2017      51
2017      52 (typically, not guaranteed to be 52 periods)
2018      1
2018      2
2018      3
2018      4
-------------^
2018      5
...
```

and I want to select all rows between 2017 (5) and 2018 (4) inclusive, how do I do this? I have tried several different way, but can't figure it out. Typically the pay periods are 1-52, but I can't count on that.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Do you have a large volume of data?  Is it more important to have simple maintainable code, or to optimise the query for use of indexes?

Answer (score 6):

One option

```
Select * 
 from YourTable
 Where ([Year]*100)+[PayPeriod] between 201705 and 201804
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can handle this with two conditions.

```
declare @yr int = 2018, @period = 5;

select * from t
where
       yr = @yr     and period <= @period
    or yr = @yr - 1 and period >= @period
```

I don't know how you will be passing the cutoff period but there are a number of approaches that might be appropriate:

```
-- period number is supplied as an argument
with lp(last_period) as (
    select 4
)
select yr, period
from T cross join lp
where
        yr = year(current_timestamp)     and period <= last_period 
    or  yr = year(current_timestamp) - 1 and period >= last_period;


-- assumes the "last" row in the table is the cutoff
with lp(last_period) as (
    select distinct first_value(period) over (order by yr desc, period desc)
    from T 
)
select yr, period
from T cross join lp
where
        yr >= year(current_timestamp) - 1
    and yr  = year(current_timestamp) or period >= last_period;


-- calculates period based on current date??
with lp(last_period) as (
    select datepart(week, current_timestamp)
)
select yr, period
from T cross join lp
where
        yr = year(current_timestamp)     and period <= last_period 
    or  yr = year(current_timestamp) - 1 and period >= last_period;
```

Comment: `Typically the pay periods are 1-52, but I can't count on that.`

Answer (score 0):

If there are a low number of rows, I would go with the answer from @JohnCappelletti.  It is simple and easy to understand.

If you have a large number of rows, and need to optimise the query for use of indexes, then you want to avoid calculations on the fields you are searching *(and avoid `OR` conditions too)*.  As such I would use something like...

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yr = 2016 AND period >= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yr = 2017 AND period <  5
```

Really though, I'd recommend changing the structure of the table.  As you've discovered it "awkward" to filter on a range when you've separated the scale over two fields.

One option could be to use a `DATE` field that represents the start of each pay period.

Or perhaps having a separate table with each reporting period...

```
CREATE TABLE dim_pay_period (
  id               INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  start_date       DATE,
  year             INT,
  period           INT,          -- The 1-52(ish) that you're using
  year_period      INT,          -- 201705, for example
  num_working_days INT           -- Just an example...
)
```

Then your data table would have a single column "pay_year_period" and you could just join against the dimension table if you needed to find out information about that year_period.